# Save file with FileOutputStream does not create any file

Tags: java, android, savestate

Currently I'm developing an android app where the user has to click on a button this adds +1 to a count. After 100 there is another button which causes a reset of the count and increase the level and difficulty which is stored in another 2 "ints". Well its all working but I seriously have big problems with creating a save file.

1. -I gave me the permission via `AndroidManifest.xml`
2. -Tryed 3 other code examples
3. - I did import everything that is necessary and the rest of the code is working

There has to be a mistake in this part of my code:

(my part for the Saving the "Stats")

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {
                FileOutputStream savelvl = openFileOutput("savelvl.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                savelvl.write(level);
                savelvl.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

can anyone suggest an improvement to the code or tell me the mistake in saving the file to the internal storage?

Comment: Any exceptions in logcat?

Comment: Sorry I'd forget to metntion im quiet new to app programming , could you tell me how  logcat would help me?

Comment: openFileOutput() does not require any Manifest permission, so please remove any you have mistakenly added on account of that.  You haven't stated what your actual problem is, but it's almost as likely to be with the reading as with the writing.

Comment: My problem would be that there is no savelvl.data created; the reading would be an easier part if i just could save the int value first; at least i guess it would be

Comment: How are you determining that there is no "savelvl.data" created?  That file is not going to be easy to see.

Comment: Hope there might be some exception other than `FileNotFoundException` and `IOException`, so catch the `Exception` and see if you have any other exceptions and that will let you know the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with using a BufferedWriter instead of FileOutputStream, although I'm sure it could given a different setup. Below is some code with "FileOutputStream out", which I was trying to use initially, commented out.

```
BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
            //out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.i("file","file opened");
            writer.write(someString);
            //out.write(someString.getBytes());
            Log.i("file","file written");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("fileNotFound","file not found exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }/*
        try {
            out.write(someString.getBytes());
            Log.i("file","file written");
            Log.i("str2File",someString.getBytes().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("fileWrite","file write error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/ finally {
            try {
                //out.getFD().sync();
                //out.close();
                writer.close();
                Log.i("file","file closed");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("closeError","error closing file");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot flush your data. When you use writer you must call flush method after write method.

```
OutputStrem stream = ... // I cannot create new reference because "OutStream" class is abstract
stream.write(data, offset, length);
stream.flush();
stream.close();
```

Comment: As a general principle, I'd be very surprised if close() does not involve an implicit flush() - however the documentation for Android's OutputStream and FileOutputStream give the appearance that FileOutputStream *does not* override the *do-nothing* flush() it inherits from OutputStream.

Comment: You' re right my mistake. I mixed buffered mechanism.